# Integrate a function and specify other parameters in r

Tags: r

Let's say I want to integrate the function

```
integrand <- function(x, a) exp(a*x)
```

where `x` is my covariate and `a` is simply a number specified by the user. How do I integrate this in **R**? I know you can do something like:

```
integrand <- function(x) {1/((x+1)*sqrt(x))}
integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
```

But how can I supply other parameters? I am thinking that I probably need some kind of `expression` or `eval` function, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
integrand <- function(x, a) exp(a*x)
integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = Inf, a=-1)
```

Have a look at `?integrate` and you'll see

```
integrate(f, lower, upper, ..., subdivisions = 100L,
          rel.tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25, abs.tol = rel.tol,
          stop.on.error = TRUE, keep.xy = FALSE, aux = NULL)

Arguments

f            an R function taking a numeric first argument and returning a numeric vector of the same length. Returning a non-finite element will generate an error.
lower, upper the limits of integration. Can be infinite.
...          additional arguments to be passed to f.
```

So you can pass as many arguments as *integrand* needs as fourth argument and they will be passed to the function before integrating it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a million!!! That will teach me for not reaching the documentation carefully enough...